Is there any deeper explanation behind this simple acoustic experiment?
my question is a bit inconvenient but let me explain:
I recently saw an experiment for primary school where two strings are attended to a coat hanger (see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yx8yOO6_3c, hope its okay to share the link but otherwise it would be hard to explain what you are doing in this experiment).
I am a physics graduate student and I read through many explanation that are given for this experiment. All are using the fact that sound travels faster through matter and some are also mentioning losses in air. I don't think these explanations get to the heart of this phenomena and I wanted to ask here, if anyone knows if someone has done some serious research about this phenomena.
The research questions that I would be interested in would be like: Could we actually measure the difference from the frequency spectrum, or is there any and why does it even change? Or compared to the tin can phone: Where is the resonator here? Do my fingers take the role of the can in the tin can phone experiment?
I would be extremely glad, if someone could help me! :)
Thanks in advance.

Stack Exchange questions must be self-contained. They may link to additional supporting material, but the question has to be understandable without the links.

The experiment is essentially a tin can phone with a different design. In a can phone, the vibrating sound energy is transduced at one end from air to the tin/string and then back into the air inside the can at the other end, and because it is kept restricted to a small volume the energy does not disperse much and ends up exciting you eardrums. Here in this
video, the vibrations from the wire travel on the cord and fingers, and gets transduced into air inside your small ear cavity, so the energy cannot spread much (like inside the cup in the telephone) and excites your eardrums way stronger than if the sound was dispersed outside the ear.
I think the role of the can as a resonant cavity is taken by the inside of your ear, the finger does not play a role much different that the cord, you just need to shift from a thin cord into a second solid  that fits the entrance of the ear cavity.

Thanks, this already helps a bit! :) I would try to measure the volume with different string thickness. That would explain, why it is so loud. But still, this doesn't explain why it sounds so different (not only the volume but you here a very clear 'gong' like from these chines gongs, this is still not clear to me, maybe a frequency analysis would help?)

remember that here the waves on the first end  are generated not by the transduction of sound waves, but from hitting a wire. In such a case, do you have any preconceived ideas of what kind of sound you should expect.  I would not be surprised to hear  gong like sounds or even a cat's meow! the interactions and transductions are complicated, I am not sure how difficult would it be to simulate that.
